# SWIG: Problems with inheriting from a template and function overloading

Tags: c++, matlab, swig

EDIT:
OK I tried to reduce my code to the Example and it seems to work in the small example. I try to rebuild the error from the small example. So the example shown below doesn't contain the cause of the problem.

I want to wrap a class which inherits from a template for Matlab with swig.

```
   template<class T>
   class Base {
   public:
      typedef Base<T>* Pointer;
      void create(typename ::Base< T >::Pointer src) {
      ... 
      };
   }
   class Derived : public Base<float> {
      //overloading because I hide it by overloading with other parameters
      // && using isn't working in the tool set.
      void create(typename ::Base< float >::Pointer src) {
         Base::create(src);
      };
   }
```

For Derived swig generates creates two overloading wrappers one that is taking ::Base< float >::Pointer and one that is taking ::Base< T >::Pointer. The T isn't replaced by float and so doesn't compile because T is unknown.

Can you suggest anything I can try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you(I) let some using (`using Base::create`) statments, so swig also includes them to Derived, but doesn't resolve the Type parameter for them.